# Drop n-1 rows when there are n rows are identical in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my problem. For example, there is a dataframe showed like this:

```
### df
Name Code Mass 
a01   j1  0.55
a01   j1  0.55
a01   j1  0.55
a02   j2  0.33
a02   j2  0.33
a03   j3  0.23
a04   j4  0.23
```

There are several rows are identical(e.g, rows with **Name** "a01").

I want to leave one row behind and drop the redundancy.

My target dataframe should showed like this:

```
>df
Name Code Mass 
a01   j1  0.55
a02   j2  0.33
a03   j3  0.23
a04   j4  0.23
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df.drop_duplicates())
  Name Code  Mass
0  a01   j1  0.55
3  a02   j2  0.33
5  a03   j3  0.23
6  a04   j4  0.23
```

It is same as with parameter `keep='first'`, because `first` is by default:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(keep='first'))
  Name Code  Mass
0  a01   j1  0.55
3  a02   j2  0.33
5  a03   j3  0.23
6  a04   j4  0.23
```

You can also use:

```
#keep last value
print (df.drop_duplicates(keep='last'))
  Name Code  Mass
2  a01   j1  0.55
4  a02   j2  0.33
5  a03   j3  0.23
6  a04   j4  0.23

#drop all duplicates
print (df.drop_duplicates(keep=False))
  Name Code  Mass
5  a03   j3  0.23
6  a04   j4  0.23
```